# Check if a condition is met before pushing a property into array ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was wondering if someone knows a method that would allow me to push a data property into an array if a condition is met. For example, the code I'm using fetches data from an api. The data that I'm looking for specifically are the pictures. Here is my code:

```
     for (const key in petData.animals) {
        loadedData.push({
          id: key,
          photo: petData.animals[key].photos[0],
          name: petData.animals[key].name,
          description: petData.animals[key].description,
        });
      }
```

My issue stems from the fact that some of the data entries lack photos. So whenever I actually run the app, I get an error saying that photos is undefined. Is it possible to add a condition (and if so, how?) similar to if photo === undefined => use a default picture or if the photo === true => use the photo from the api?

Comment: Use null coalescing operator `??`, ie `photo: petData.animals[key].photos[0] ?? DEFAULT_PHOTO`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do this previous to the last few years was to check incrementally, like so:

```
for (const key in petData.animals) {
  let photo = defaultPhoto;
  if (petData.animals[key].photos && petData.animals[key].photos[0]) {
    photo = petData.animals[key].photos[0];
  }
  loadedData.push({
    id: key,
    photo: photo,
    name: petData.animals[key].name,
    description: petData.animals[key].description,
  });
}
```

However, we now have the [optional chaining operator (`?.`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) and [nullish coalescing operator (`??`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) so we can do this more concisely, like so:

```
for (const key in petData.animals) {
  loadedData.push({
    id: key,
    photo: petData.animals[key]?.photos?.[0] ?? defaultPhoto,
    name: petData.animals[key].name,
    description: petData.animals[key].description,
  });
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you!